# defining a divisible variable but prints out 0.00

Tags: c

```
//when I am trying to make a division in a float variable for some reason it
//prints 000

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
  float price , discount  , total ;

  scanf ("%f",&price);

  if (price > 99 && price < 201)  
    discount = 10/100;   
    // i can also set <<discount>> variable 0.10  
  else if (price < 301)    
    // but i can t understand why this way prints 00  
    discount = 10/100;
  else if (price <401)  
    discount = 20/100;  
  else  
    discount = 30/100;

  total = price - discount;
  printf ("tha exete ekptwsei %.2f",discount);
}
```

Comment: Add a ".0" or an "f" after every number. Else they will be truncated and then converted to floating point.

Comment: ohh thank you very much, i am new in c language i prefer c++ and python

Comment: my code had the same view but stackoverflow for some reason wanted to have 4 /t space to let me post my code, tvm btw

Comment: With respect to integer division, C behaves like C++ and unlike Python.

Comment: When formatting code for presentation on SO, make sure you use blanks, not tabs, to indent (or detab the code before copy'n'pasting).  Copy the code into the question (or answer) box (ignore the preview at this stage), making sure there are no tabs in the code.  Select the code, use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it as code.  Now check the preview.

Comment: have you ever divided a number in C++ or python 2? The behavior in those languages are exactly the same as this case, which is similar to python 3 `//`

Comment: yes, i had forget the fact when i have to deivide 2 numbers those numbers must be writen for example 2.0 in c++ this process was automated

Answer (score 4):

```
if (price > 99 && price < 301)
    discount = 10.0/100.0;   
else if (price <401)  
    discount = 20.0/100.0;   
else  
    discount = 30.0/100.0;
```

Update 
Only .0 in divider is suffice like 10/100.0